# What's the best way to run a platform with multiple git repositories with Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application platform that is built in PHP and consists of multiple applications that live in different Git repositories.

It is my understanding that you can only run an AWS Elastic Beanstalk with one Git repository feeding it.

Is there any way I can run one EB Environment that feeds from multiple Git repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, Elastic beanstalk provide ability to customize environment with help of configuration files. See details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html.

If you need to pull your applications from different github repositories you can do in following way: create configuration file with bootstrap script with will pull applications from your github repositories instead of publishing via git aws.push.

Your know how does work git aws.push? This command push source to the aws service with create zip file with your source and then put it on the s3 bucket. Then call environment update and provide link to s3 bucket.

Also in it possible to pull your projects locally. Then create zip bundle with sources and scripts in .ebextenctions which will deploy your applications.

Answer (score 2):

I have since discovered that this is just no possible. AWS only allows one Git repository to be deployed to an EB Environment at any one time.

Git sub modules could be the answer to the problem, but I don't agree with them.

Luckily AWS provide another semi-managed solution: AWS OpsWorks.

For anyone else struggling with the same issue I did above, then you should definitely try it.

http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I am replying for someone stumbling on it from google, like I did.

One way I found to solve this issue is to build the .zip bundle to be uploaded to AWS Eleastic Beanstalk by yourself and configure EB CLI to use that. Here is the relevant piece of documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact

You can have a simple script to run git archive(s), combine all this into one .zip file as your project needs it (or run any build process you might require) and then deploy that.